# JQuery Selecting a specific Value in a div when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I need to grab the text from the third instance of row11 (lib_data[3]) when clicking on the Add File Link - code is as follows:-

```
lb+="<div class='row_container2'>
     <div class='row11'>"+lib_data[2]+"</div>
     <div class='row11'>"+lib_data[1]+"</div>
     <div class='row11'>"+lib_data[3]+"</div>
     <div class='row11'>
     <a href='sym.php?doc_id="+lib_data[0]+"' class='view_file'>View File</a>
      | 
     <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='select_doc' data-file='"+lib_data[0]+"' data-file_name='"+lib_data[1]+"'>Add File</a>
    </div>
    <br style='clear:both'>";
lb+="</div>";
lb+="<div class='hidden_lib'>";
lb+="</div>";
```

JQuery so far:-

```
var document_desc=$(this).parent().parent().text();
```

Unfortunately this seems to get all the text from each div. Is there any way to specify the row needed ?

Comment: Please replace the string concatonation of your HTML with the actual HTML rendred as what is currently posted is of little use to any other user may be looking for a similar solution to a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this script:

```
$('.row_container2 .row11').eq(2).html();
```

Here's an example [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9jwmC/10/)

Comment: This works well - unfortunately the others don't return a value :)

Comment: unfortunately it does not access the variables when there are multiple rows.#

Comment: Could you edit the HTML in my DEMO? Then I can update the jQuery to work with this new HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$("div .row11:eq(2)").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(this).parent().parent().eq(2).text();
```

The problem with your approach is , parent.parent gets the div row_container2 and not your desired child div

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('.row_container2 .row11')[2]
```

Comment: [2] will return the reference to the element in the DOM not the html value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Think I have sorted the problem. I reall should have specified originally that the div will be looped depending on the number of entries in the list. My solution, along with the help here is as follows:-

```
$(this).closest('.row_container2').children('.row11:eq(2)').text();
```